# Unable to select text from dropdown - Gmail.com Month Dropdown

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, selenium-webdriver

Im also facing the same error. Unable to select Birthday, Gender & Location
in gmail signup page.
I'm using Selenium Webdriver.

Please find the below code for birthday.

```
new Select (driver.findElement(By.id(":0"))).selectByValue("January");
```

On executing the above code it gives me the below error

### > Element should have been "select" but was "div".

### Following is the complete code.

```
public class GmailCreate {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.get("http://gmail.com");
        //By genderDropdown = By.xpath("//*[@id='Gender']/div");
        driver.findElement(By.id("link-signup")).click();
        /*driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("ABC");
        driver.findElement(By.id("LastName")).sendKeys("XYZ");
        driver.findElement(By.id("GmailAddress")).sendKeys("abcx0429");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("pass1word123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("PasswdAgain")).sendKeys("pass1word123");
        //new Select (driver.findElement(By.id(":0"))).selectByValue("January");
         //Select gender = new Select(driver.findElement(genderDropdown));
           // gender.selectByVisibleText("Male");*/

        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='BirthMonth']/div")).click();
       Thread.sleep(2000);
       // driver.findElement(By.id(":3")).click();


    /*  driver.findElement(By.id("BirthDay")).sendKeys("26");
        driver.findElement(By.id("BirthYear")).sendKeys("1988");
        driver.findElement(By.id("RecoveryPhoneNumber")).sendKeys("9876543210");
        driver.findElement(By.id("RecoveryEmailAddress")).sendKeys("abcxyz@gmail.com");

        if ( !driver.findElement(By.id("SkipCaptcha")).isSelected() )
        {
             driver.findElement(By.id("SkipCaptcha")).click();
             System.out.println("Marked");
        }
        else
        {
             System.out.println("Already Marked");
        }

        if (!driver.findElement(By.id("TermsOfService")).isSelected())
        {
            driver.findElement(By.id("TermsOfService")).click();
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton")).click();*/

        WebElement monthDropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select goog-flat-menu-button-focused goog-flat-menu-button-hover']"));  

     // Select month
     Select month= new Select(monthDropdown);
     month.selectByVisibleText("March");

     // enter birth day       
     WebElement DayTbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='BirthDay']"));
     DayTbox.clear();
     DayTbox.sendKeys("20");

     // Enter Birth Year 
     WebElement YearTbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='BirthYear']")); 
     YearTbox.clear();
     YearTbox.sendKeys("2010");


    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to GUI automated gmail?

Comment: I have just started learning automation. so i was doing it for practice. i would appreciate if ppl help me with the issues instead of asking irrelevant questions. Thank You..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WebElement monthDropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select goog-flat-menu-button-focused goog-flat-menu-button-hover']"));  

// Select month
Select month= new Select(monthDropdown);
month.selectByVisibleText("March");

// enter birth day       
WebElement DayTbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='BirthDay']"));
DayTbox.clear();
DayTbox.sendKeys("20");

// Enter Birth Year 
WebElement YearTbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='BirthYear']")); 
YearTbox.clear();
YearTbox.sendKeys("2010");
```

Check for Gmail sign up, It works fine...

Comment: Above code is working fine on my PC for Gmail sign up.

Comment: paste your code here..

Comment: I have edited my Question and copied the entire code.. Please ignore the commented code..

Answer (score 3):

```
    // How old are you?
    Select Agefield = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("agefieldXpath")));
    Agefield.selectByVisibleText("26-35");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    // What is your gender?
    Select gender = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("genderfieldXpath")));
    gender.selectByVisibleText("Male");
```

Try with this..
definitely it will works.

Comment: is it works iAutomate  ?

Comment: No it did not work.
On executing the above code it gives me the below error

 Element should have been "select" but was "div"
Actually it is not a drop down as u can see same thing mentioned by Arun.

Comment: once confirm your 'xpath' or 'id' is correct or not. Is it drop-down list?
paste your code here.
You may use selectByindex() method....

Comment: HTML code for the field i am trying to select value from.

<span id="BirthMonth">
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select" role="listbox" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-activedescendant=":0" title="Birthday">
<div id=":0" class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" role="option" aria-setsize="12" aria-posinset="0">Month</div>
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
</div>
<input id="HiddenBirthMonth" type="hidden" name="BirthMonth">
</span>

Comment: On facebook the HTML has tag as <Select>. but in Gmail it is <div>. so the same java code will not work for both the fields.

Comment: so you don't know how to locate xpath....? I am talking about how to select (click) element from drop down list, and now your problem is ..you dont have idea about xpath...
just give me you your site URL...

Comment: Check now, below I have added new code for Gmail sign up---
If it works, accept this by clicking

Comment: Buddy i know how to locate Xpath.. locating a field and putting a value in that fields are two different things.. anyways. following is the URL:.
https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default

Comment: dude, I have already added new code for google sign up, check below-- 
If it not works then inform me

Comment: No. it did not work. Error- Element should have been "select" but was "div". i have used xpath as "//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div"  and it doesn't recognize the xpath suggested by your code.

Comment: boss check below code, I have already added different xpath & it is working on my PC.

Comment: I dnt see any code below.. There is no code in your comment..

Comment: WebElement monthDropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select goog-flat-menu-button-focused goog-flat-menu-button-hover']"));  

// Select month
Select month= new Select(monthDropdown);
month.selectByVisibleText("March");

// enter birth day       
WebElement DayTbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='BirthDay']"));
DayTbox.clear();
DayTbox.sendKeys("20");

// Enter Birth Year 
WebElement YearTbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='BirthYear']")); 
YearTbox.clear();
YearTbox.sendKeys("2010");

Comment: Not in comment, check in 3rd answer.
check xpath of month, Year & Day field.

Comment: not working..  
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select goog-flat-menu-button-focused goog-flat-menu-button-hover']"}
Command duration or timeout: 3.83 seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page structure i.e. here gmail-Signup page,  Birthday, Gender & Location is not more a dropdown with select tag. So if you are using select in WebDriver, you will get the above error. Please try replacing with the below code. It worked for me.

```
Birthday Field:
WebElement listbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='BirthMonth']/div"));
listbox.click();
```

Then do the same for Gender & Location.

**Note:** Inspecting the element with <kbd>F12</kbd> will give you a clear idea.

Comment: Thanks Arun. Appreciate ur help.. bt the code will only click on the field and show the available Months. but it doesn't select a month to proceed. can u help with that?

Answer (score 0):

well this code will work..

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]"))).click().sendKeys(Keys.UP).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Comment: we can make it more tuned as the arrow will start from the location that is provided to start from january month we need to focus our driver instance to the january option before using sendkeys to select the right one for us.

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div")).click();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':1']/div"))).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

Comment: Thanks @swagat i got the same issue and the solution helped me

Answer (score 0):

If this problem still actual. Try this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]")).SendKeys("Feb")
```